How to connect graphical interface with tcp server class
I am trying to create a local cloud for my family.I have 2 classes:TcpServer class:
public class TcpServer
{
    ServerSocket s;

    Socket[]sockets = {};

    GUIHandler guiHandler;

    String message = "";

    int messageId = 0;


    public TcpServer(int port)
    {
        try {
            s = new ServerSocket(port);

            System.out.println("IP Address:"+s.getInetAddress().getHostName());
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Cannot create a TCP Server on port:"+port);
        }
}
public void Listen()
{
    while(true)
    {
     try
     {
       Socket socket = s.accept();

       message = socket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress();

       messageId = 0;

       sendMessageToGUIHandler();

       System.out.println("Connected to host:"+socket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress());
     }
     catch(Exception e)
     {
         System.out.println("Couldnt bind to socket");
     }

    }
}
public void connectToGUIHandler(GUIHandler gu)
{
    guiHandler = gu;
}
public void sendMessageToGUIHandler()
{
guiHandler.updateGUI(message,messageId);
}
}

which handles the exchange of messages between 2 or more different computers and the GUIHandler class which handles the graphical interface:
public class GUIHandler {

    TcpServer tcpServer;

    JFrame jframe;

    public GUIHandler()
    {
        jframe = new JFrame("Interlink");

        jframe.setSize(400,300);

        jframe.setVisible(true);
    }
    public void connectToTCPServer(TcpServer tcs)
    {
        tcpServer = tcs;
    }
    public void updateGUI(String message,int messageId)
    {
        if(messageId==0)
        {
            JDialog jdialog = new JDialog(jframe,"Warning");

            JLabel jlabel = new JLabel(message);

            JButton buttonYes = new JButton("No");

            buttonYes.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                }
            });
        }
    }
}

The classes are linked with 2 methods 1  in each class which maps one instance of the GUIHandler class to the TcpServer class.Now I have written down a function which takes as input fields of the TcpServer class and updates the GUI.In my case I want when a new Tcp connection is detected a message dialog to be popped up.However this dialog box will have 2 buttons , yes and no and when no is pressed it closes the socket of the income connection and when yes is pressed it just adds it to the array of connected sockets.
Which means I have to send data from the GUIHandler to the TcpServer class.The tricky part is that the assosciated socket must be called (when no is pressed to close the socket and when yes is pressed to keep the socket open) so the assosciated socket must be a parameter to the function of the GUIHandler function but the GUIHandler function doesnt have any information on the socket.So how do I solve this issue?

Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Sorry, but this site is not a discussion forum or programming tutorial site.
Please take the [tour], visit the [help] and read [Ask] to learn how to use this site effectively.
Network client/server code invariably requires multi-threading (one to listen and one for each connection). Otherwise your server cannot handle more than one connection at a time.
